# Updating JSON file using PHP causes duplicate entries

Tags: php, arrays, json, forms, duplicates

I am trying to use PHP forms to update a JSON file, but when I edit a field of the file, it creates a duplicate of the entry, but with the updated information. For example:

```
[
    {"toolName":"tool1", "url":"https://google.com/", "phase":"None"},
    {"toolName":"tool2", "url":"http://yahoo.com/", "phase":"None"},
    {"toolName":"tool3", "url":"http://bing.com/", "phase":"None"}
]
```

If on submission the PHP form wants to change the "phase" for "tool1", it adds a new entry with the updates. Like:

```
[
    {"toolName":"tool1", "url":"https://google.com/", "phase":"None"},
    {"toolName":"tool2", "url":"http://yahoo.com/", "phase":"None"},
    {"toolName":"tool3", "url":"http://bing.com/", "phase":"None"},
    {"toolName":"tool1", "url":"https://google.com/", "phase":"NewPhase"}
]
```

How can this be avoided? I am using the index of the tool in the array as the identifier when I update, so my current solution is this:

```
$toolId = $_POST['tool-id'];
$toolName = $_POST['tool-name'];
$toolUrl = $_POST['tool-url'];
$toolPhase = $_POST['tool-phase'];

$data = file_get_contents("../assets/js/tools.json");
$json_data = json_decode($data, true);

$json_data[$toolId]->toolName = $toolName;
$json_data[$toolId]->url = $toolUrl;
$json_data[$toolId]->phase = $toolPhase;

$json_data = array_values($json_data);

file_put_contents("../assets/js/tools.json", stripslashes(json_encode($json_data)));
```

**Note: When submitting the form, I am using a Bootstrap modal, so I am only sending the data for the current visible tool (i.e. the tool at index "toolId"), so I do not iterate through the entire JSON file.

Comment: You need to store it as an associative array with `$toolId` as the key. When you do `array_values($json_data)` you lose the keys.

Comment: `$_POST['tool-id']` should contain `0` which is the index of `tool1` make sure that there's no additional noise added to that value

Comment: Also don't `stripslashes` on the json encoded value. `json_encode` knows how to produce valid json and stripping slashes may break it

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The true statement in this line instructs PHP to return an array

```
$json_data = json_decode($data, true);
```

However, these lines create an object

```
$json_data[$toolId]->toolName = $toolName;
$json_data[$toolId]->url = $toolUrl;
$json_data[$toolId]->phase = $toolPhase;
```

If you change them to this it should work

```
$json_data[$toolId]['toolName'] = $toolName;
$json_data[$toolId]['url'] = $toolUrl;
$json_data[$toolId]['phase'] = $toolPhase;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful and seems to have resolved the issue!